# Measure theory $\mu(\lim \inf E_n) \leq \lim \inf E_n$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be some measurable sets. Define $\lim \inf E_n$ to be

$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{m = n}^\infty E_m$$

I want to show that $\mu(\lim \inf E_n) \leq \lim \inf E_n$. I thought we might take an increasing sequence $(F_n)$ where $F_n = E_1 \cup ... \cup E_n$ and use that $\mu(\lim \inf F_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\bigcap_{m = n}^\infty F_m)$, but I am stuck at relation $\bigcap_{m = n}^\infty F_m$ to the $E_n$ sequence and I don't see how the $\lim \inf$ of a sequence factors in.

Comment: You can also try Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Do you mean $\mu (\lim\inf E_n) \le \lim\inf \mu(E_n)$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194833/liminf-inequality-in-measure-spaces/3737825#3737825

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X_n = \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} E_m$ is an increasing sequence of sets, hence $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n) = \lim \mu(X_n)$ by sigma additivity. But $X_n\subset E_n$, hence $\mu(X_n)\le \mu(E_n)$. Hence
\begin{equation}
\mu(\liminf E_n) = \lim \mu(X_n) = \liminf\mu(X_n)\le\liminf\mu(E_n)
\end{equation}